# Checking CSV By awk Condition By Condition

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have two Conditions with two different results to make in new CSV file.

I used awk reading all the csv file and checking if the 1st condition is work give us result and copy the line to new CSV.
another condition I've used with different result.
the line that has the 2nd condition will also be copied to the same CSV.

My code:

```
     zcat "$FileName" | awk -F'\t' '($3 ~/\.jar/ || /\.msi/ || /\.dll/ || /\.cab/ || /\.exe/ || /\.rar/ || /\.mar/ || /\.tar/ || /\.gz/ || /\.upd/ || /\.bin/ || /\.zip/ || /\.pogo/ || /\.dcr/ || /\.qgi/ || /\.deb/ || /\.ipa/ || /symantec/ || /windowsupdate/ || /\.kaspersky/ || /adobe\.com/) && $42 ~/7/ && ($15 ~/androiddownloadmanager/ && /\.apk/ && /\.pak/ && /\.vpx/) {Str="SW Download:  " $3;print Str > "New.csv"}'



     zcat "$FileName" | awk -F'\t' '(($4 >=300) && ($4 <=399)) {Str="Redirect:  " $3;print Str > "New.csv"}'
```

the result is that i'v new csv with just the line with the 2nd condition.

Thanks

Comment: What was the question again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `>>` to append contents to a file

`>` redirection will overwrite if file already exists

so, the second command would be:

```
zcat "$FileName" | awk -F'\t' '(($4 >=300) && ($4 <=399)) {Str="Redirect:  " $3;print Str >> "New.csv"}'
```

Further Reading: [Redirecting Output of print and printf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html)

Answer (score 1):

You're using `>` instead of `>>` but why are you doing the output redirection from within awk instead of in the shell? Also, why are you populating a variable with the result of string concatenation, which is slow, instead of just printing the values? You can also abbreviate your regexp a bit. Just do:

```
zcat "$FileName" | awk -F'\t' -v OFS=':  ' '($3 ~/\.jar/ || /(\.(msi|dll|cab|exe|rar|mar|tar|gz|upd|bin|zip|pogo|dcr|qgi|deb|ipa|kaspersky)|symantec|windowsupdate|adobe\.com/) && $42 ~/7/ && ($15 ~/androiddownloadmanager/ && /\.apk/ && /\.pak/ && /\.vpx/) {print "SW Download", $3}' > New.csv

zcat "$FileName" | awk -F'\t' -v OFS=':  ' '($4 >=300) && ($4 <=399) {print "Redirect", $3}' >> New.csv
```